# Vagrant execute command line user level

Tags: vagrant, ubuntu-16.04

Would you assist me in executing commands at the user-level when building a VM using vagrant? Specifically, I'm trying to update the "launcher icons" on the left side of Ubuntu's screen. In the below vagrantfile, I've attempted this in both the inline shell and an inline script. I would appreciate any assistance you can provide.

```
$script = <<SCRIPT
    echo "Configuring Launcher Icons..."
    gsettings set com.canonical.Unity.Launcher favorites "['application://org.gnome.Nautilus.desktop', 'application://chromium-browser.desktop', 'unity://running-apps', 'application://terminator.desktop', 'unity://expo-icon', 'unity://devices']"
    service lightdm restart
SCRIPT

Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|
    config.vm.box = "box-cutter/ubuntu1604-desktop"

    config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
        # Display the VirtualBox GUI when booting the machine
        vb.gui = true
        vb.name = "UpdateLauncherIcons"

        # Customize the amount of memory on the VM:
        vb.memory = "4096"
    end

    config.vm.provision "shell", inline: <<-SHELL
        # Update OS
        apt-get update
        apt-get upgrade
        apt-get --yes install git
        apt-get --yes install terminator
        apt-get --yes install chromium-browser

        gsettings set com.canonical.Unity.Launcher favorites "['application://org.gnome.Nautilus.desktop', 'application://chromium-browser.desktop', 'unity://running-apps', 'application://terminator.desktop', 'unity://expo-icon', 'unity://devices']"
        service lightdm restart

    SHELL

    config.vm.provision "shell", inline: $script

end
```

Note, vagrant does provide an error message when the inline script is executed:

```
==> default: Running provisioner: shell...
default: Running: inline script
==> default: Configuring Launcher Icons...
==> default:
==> default: (process:6221): dconf-WARNING **: failed to commit changes to dconf: Cannot autolaunch D-Bus without X11 $DISPLAY
```

Further testing confirms that the below command work well when executed in the guest machine within a terminal window. Again, the challenge is getting this command to work from the vagrantfile executed on the host.

```
gsettings set com.canonical.Unity.Launcher favorites "['application://org.gnome.Nautilus.desktop', 'application://chromium-browser.desktop', 'unity://running-apps', 'application://terminator.desktop', 'unity://expo-icon', 'unity://devices']"
```

Comment: `sudo -u vagrant <whatever>` in your inline provisioner.

Comment: @CodeGnome I tried your advice and used:  

`sudo -u vagrant gsettings set com.canonical.Unity.Launcher favorites "['application://org.gnome.Nautilus.desktop', 'unity://running-apps', 'application://terminator.desktop', 'unity://expo-icon', 'unity://devices']"`

but, I still receive an error message within the host terminal running vagrantfile:

`==> default: (process:5495): dconf-CRITICAL **: unable to create directory '/root/.cache/dconf': Permission de
nied.  dconf will not work properly.`

Do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: Why are you creating anything as root? The vagrant user is usually `vagrant` or `ubuntu`, and runs as root using sudo by default. I think you may to explain a bit more about what permissions and locations you're dealing with, as this is clearly a permissions problem.

Comment: @CodeGnome I'm not intentionally creating anything as root; I'm simply trying to utilize vagrant to generate a reproducible environment (see the vagrantfile I posted originally). I don't understand why the `gettings set ...` command doesn't work when executed from the vagrantfile, but it works perfectly when executed on the guest machine. I would appreciate any further direction and/or assistance you can provide.

Answer (score 0):

Haven't used Ubuntu Desktop Vagrant boxes for a long time, but a similar setup in one of our team projects use "privileged: false" for the shell provisioner:

```
config.vm.provision "shell", privileged: false, path: "scripts/setup-desktop.sh"
config.vm.provision "shell", privileged: false, path: "scripts/configure-desktop.sh"
```

as well as a provision script setting auto login

```
echo "autologin-user=vagrant" | sudo tee -a /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf

# restart desktop
sudo service lightdm restart
```

the next provision script then uses some autostart features to run it

```
#!/bin/bash

#modify shortcuts on ubuntu cause that are used in eclipse
cat <<AUTOSTART_SHORTCUTS | sudo tee /home/vagrant/bin/modify-shortcuts
#!/bin/sh
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-down []
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-up []
#Disable Resize window (Alt + F8)
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings begin-resize []
#Disable move window (Alt + F7)
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings begin-move []

AUTOSTART_SHORTCUTS
sudo chmod 777 /home/vagrant/bin/modify-shortcuts

cat <<GSETTINGS | sudo tee /home/vagrant/bin/setup-unity
#!/bin/sh
# set favourites in launcher
gsettings set  com.canonical.Unity.Launcher favorites "['application://nautilus.desktop', 'application://gnome-terminal.desktop', 'application://firefox.desktop', 'application://chromium-browser.desktop', 'application://gvim.desktop', 'application://IDEA.desktop']"

# set german keyboard
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.input-sources sources "[('xkb', 'de'), ('xkb', 'us')]"

#Disabling screensaver
#gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.screensaver idle-activation-enabled false
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.session idle-delay 0

# disable screensaver locking desktop
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.screensaver lock-enabled false

# cleanup
sudo rm -f /home/vagrant/.config/autostart/setup-unity.desktop
GSETTINGS
sudo chmod 777 /home/vagrant/bin/setup-unity

mkdir -p .config/autostart

cat <<AUTOSTART_SHORTCUTS_DT | sudo tee /home/vagrant/.config/autostart/modify-shortcuts.desktop
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Exec=/home/vagrant/bin/modify-shortcuts
Hidden=false
NoDisplay=false
X-GNOME-Autostart-enabled=true
Name[en_US]=modify-shortcuts
Name=modify-shortcuts
Comment[en_US]=
Comment=
AUTOSTART_SHORTCUTS_DT
cat <<GSETTINGS_DT | sudo tee /home/vagrant/.config/autostart/setup-unity.desktop
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Exec=/home/vagrant/bin/setup-unity
Hidden=false
NoDisplay=false
X-GNOME-Autostart-enabled=true
Name[en_US]=setup-unity
Name=setup-unity
Comment[en_US]=
Comment=setup-unity
GSETTINGS_DT

# restart desktop
sudo service lightdm restart
```

Comment: I appreciate your time in locating & posting this information. I've tried using all of your suggestions without success. I hoped that "privileged: false" for the shell provisioner was the key, but it seems like I'm still missing something.